# Help finishing a sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the thousandth digit of the following sequence:
123456789101112131415161718192021

How do you know? how did you find it? (ex. the 13th digit is 1)

Comment: Note: This sequence is [A033307](https://oeis.org/A033307) on OEIS.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers 1 through 9 contribute $9$ digits to the sequence.

The numbers 10 through 99 contribute $90\cdot 2=180$ digits to the sequence.

So, starting at digit $190$ the next $900\cdot 3=3600$ digits come from concatenating all of the 4-digit numbers. What we're looking for is the $(1000-189)$th of these digits, that is, the $811$th of the digits that come from 3-digit numbers.

$810$ is $270\cdot 3$, so we're looking for the first digit of the $271$th 3-digit number.

The $271$th 3-digit number is $370$ (remember that the $1$st 3-digit number is $100$), so the digit you seek is **3**.